# How to test custom routes in controller with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

I have defined a custom route in 
routes.rb

```
get "packages/city/:location_id",  to: "packages#index"
```

In `controller_spec.rb`,

```
get :index
```

gives this error,

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"packages"}
```

How to explicitly specify the custom routes in controller specs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps it helps if you declare your route like this?

```
get "packages/city/:location_id" => "packages#index"
```

Remember to provide a `location_id` param in specs, e.g. `get :index, location_id: 1`.

Answer (score 10):

### 2017

I tried the solutions above but they did not work. I got:

```
ArgumentError:
   unknown keyword: location_id
```

It seems that RSpec now requires a `params` parameter. The corresponding call would look like this:

```
get(:index, params: { location_id: 123 })
```

Comment: I was using `:id` instead of `:location_id`

Answer (score 2):

it's because you are not passing `location_id`

the route is defined to match:

`/packages/city/:location_id`

so in order to comply with it you need to do something like

`get :index, location_id: 1234`

Had the same issue with Controller spec:

```
# rake routes | grep media_order
teacher_work_media_orders PATCH /teacher/works/:work_id/media_orders(.:format)  teacher/media_orders#update
```

when I did:

```
# spec/controller/teacher/media_orders_controller
patch :update data: {}
```

I got

```
 Failure/Error: patch :update
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"teacher/media_orders"}
```

but when I did

```
patch :update, work_id: 1234, data: {}
```

that worked

Answer (score 2):

## 2019

Was tackling this same error on my controller specs. Tried accepted and follow up solutions, but they also did not work, either led to no method error or persisted the no route match error.

Directly defining the route like in the accepted solution also did not satisfy the errors.

After much searching and some keyboard smashing tests pass.

## Things to note

- controller is for polymorphic resource
- routes are nested within the `resources :location, only[:index, :show] do ... end`
- this is API routes, so JSON only

## Solution

```
let(:location) do
    create(:location)
  end


shared_examples("a user who can't manage locations") do
    describe 'GET #index' do
      it 'denies access' do

        get :index, params:{location_id: location.locationable.id, format: :json}
        expect(response).to have_http_status :unauthorized
      end
    end
end
```

So in the end it was a combination of both solutions, but had to put them in the params hash or else it would throw name/no method or route errors

## Conclusion

- references to the association must be in the params hash
- even if controller responds_to :json, it will throw errors no route errors
- must include a data hash in your request or no route match errors will appear

Hope this helps,

Cheers!